# get pom parameters in a maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, svn, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I am developing a maven plugin. It is used at build time by other projects. This plugin uses the username and password in order to connect to an svn repository/server. This is part of this maven plugin's pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
        <releaseProfiles>complete</releaseProfiles>
        <username>${username}</username>
        <password>${password}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**I need to get the values of username and password dynamically when the plugin is running (In other words when other projects are being built)**. How can I do that?

*Thanks!*

Edit:

When other users build their project with this plugin, They don't pass their username/password through command line. (Like: -DuserName=userNameVal). But the plugin works fine and can connect to svn repository/server using their username and password. The problem is that I don't understand how this plugin get these values.

And one more thing: I need to get values in my java code. Something like this:

```
String username = getUserName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the values through commandline like below:-

> mvn install "-DuserName=userNameValue"

Then in your pom.xml you can do like below:-

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
        <releaseProfiles>complete</releaseProfiles>
        **<username>${userName}</username>**
        <password>${password}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks! But That's not my answer. I will edit my question.